Write the matrix representation of the quadratic form  (  ,  )
Write the matrix representation of the quadratic form
$$Q(x,y,z)=x^2+3z^2+2xy-xz$$
find its eigenvalues, and classify the quadratic form.
The representation is matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1& 1& -1/2 \\ 1& 0 &0 \\ -1/2& 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix} $$
But getting the eigenvalues by calculating the determinant to an annoying cubic equation. Is there a way to solve the eigenvalues of this matrix by another way: For example by substituting into x^TAx+bx^T+c
Any help is needed as I am stuck with this exercise and need enlighting.

The cubic I got is $-x^3+4 x^2-\frac{7}{4}x-3$. Finding its roots is equivalent to finding roots of $4x^3-16x^2+7x+12$. By the rational root theorem, you can find out $\frac 32$ is a rational root, which means that $$-x^3+4 x^2-\frac{7}{4}x-3 = -\frac 12 (2x-3)(x^2+ax+b).$$ After you expand the RHS, you can compare coefficients to find out $a$ and $b$, and finally, you are left with quadratic equation $x^2+ax+b=0$.
